# Column Count Splitting Padding Bottom to Next Column

Tags: html, css

In Chrome and Safari, Column Count is splitting the bottom padding of my List Item into the next column. `Display:inline-block;` on the "a" fixes this issue, but then I lose the full-width background hover effect.

I've tried re-writing the padding to a margin, but for some reason `display:block;` doesn't count the padding or bottom margin when calculating the split.

Is there a work-around to this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Codepen: http://codepen.io/roachdesign/pen/rOqjNM

Comment: `Display:inline-block;` , you mean `display:inline-block;` right

Comment: Lol, yeah, my bad on that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your rules for `break-inside` from your `ul` to your `li`.

*Change this:*

```
header nav ul li.menu-item-25 ul {
    ...
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    ...
}
```

*To:*

```
header nav ul li {
    ...
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Your modified codepen: http://codepen.io/Abhitalks/pen/YyJNQJ

The reason being, you want the column-items to avoid breaking themselves from inside instead of the column-container.

Comment: Another solutions I found was to use `display:inline:block` on the `a` and then set `width:100%;` so that the hover background was full-width. Thank you!!!

Comment: `break-inside` avoid didn't work for me. Only when I put `overflow: hidden` on the breaking element did things work as expected